# How to create a google map image mask overlay?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to create a google map "inside" an shape like in the example bellow. 
Could you please help me?
[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsGHC.png)

Comment: Reading the help section might help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you could use the `clip-path` [css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), which supports the use of separately defined clip-source values. Iframes, unfortunately do no support this method of styling. I would suggest getting an svg that is the *inverse* of the shape that you want to overlay on to the map and then position it absolutely on top of map, embedded via an iframe. Something like this:

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://svgur.com/i/Fw8.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="map">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d41290.17039912266!2d-87.72447812127052!3d41.91184942751453!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1572901622073!5m2!1sen!2sus" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
 
 
<!-- externally hosted svg looks like this:  --> 
 <svg id="mask" width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
      <title>background</title>
      <rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1" />
      <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
        <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <path id="svg_1" d="m294.37485,-50.25167c-134.48292,0 -243.50004,109.0171 -243.50004,243.5c0,134.4829 109.01712,243.5 243.50004,243.5c134.48292,0 243.50004,-109.0171 243.50004,-243.5c0,-134.4829 -109.01712,-243.5 -243.50004,-243.5zm140.49755,226.21006c-24.30979,27.96212 -62.08966,37.21023 -95.24547,26.57156l-120.42647,138.48706c-12.83343,14.74336 -35.16627,16.2512 -49.90963,3.43453s-16.30147,-35.16626 -3.48479,-49.90963l120.59401,-138.63785c-14.96116,-31.24587 -11.00726,-69.7629 13.18526,-97.57424c22.90247,-26.38726 57.85095,-36.03746 89.59944,-28.04589l-46.14002,53.81326l15.09519,43.91176l45.6039,8.86277l46.2573,-53.9473c12.53186,30.39143 7.92456,66.54617 -15.1287,93.03395z"
        stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000" />
      <rect id="svg_2" height="525" width="198" y="-61.54688" x="-49.5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000" />
      <rect id="svg_3" height="119" width="174" y="382.45313" x="96.5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000" />
      <rect id="svg_4" height="540" width="261" y="-53.54688" x="505.5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000" />
      <rect id="svg_5" height="191" width="289" y="307.45313" x="344.5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000" />
      <rect id="svg_6" height="141" width="120" y="-62.54688" x="458.5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000" />
      <rect id="svg_7" height="38" width="76" y="-15.54688" x="413.5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#000" />
    </g>
    </svg>
```

[Additional link to a version of this code on CodePen.](https://codepen.io/BriceShatzer/pen/eYYVKmr?editors=1100)